# Advice on avoiding duplicate inserts when the data is repetitive and I don't have a timestamp

Tags: mysql, database

### Details

This is a rather weird scenario. I'm trying to store records of sales from a service that I have no control over. I am just visiting a URL and storing the json it returns. It returns the last 25 sales of an item, sorted by cost, and it appears that the values will stay there for a max of 10hrs. The biggest problem is these values don't have timestamps so I can't very accurately infer how long items have been on the list and if they are duplicates.

### Example:

Say I check this url at 1pm and I get these results

```
+--------+----------+-------+
| Seller | Category | Price |
+--------+----------+-------+
| Joe    | A        |  1000 |
| Mike   | A        |  1500 |
| Sue    | B        |  2000 |
+--------+----------+-------+
```

At 2pm i get the values and they are:

```
+--------+----------+-------+
| Seller | Category | Price |
+--------+----------+-------+
| Joe    | A        |  1000 |
| Sue    | B        |  2000 |
+--------+----------+-------+
```

This would imply that Mike's sale was over 10 hrs ago and the value timed out

At 3pm:

```
+--------+----------+-------+
| Seller | Category | Price |
+--------+----------+-------+
| Joe    | A        |  1000 |
| Joe    | A        |  1000 |
| Sue    | B        |  2000 |
+--------+----------+-------+
```

This implies that Joe made 1 sale of $1000 sometime in the past 10 hours, but has also made another sale at the same price since we last checked.

### My Goal:

I'd like to be able to store each unique sale in the database once, but allow multiple sales if they do occur(I'm ok w/ only allowing only 1 sale per day if the original plan is too complicated). I realize w/o a timestamp and the potential of 25+ sales causing a value to disappear early, the results aren't going to be 100% accurate, but I'd like to be able to get an at least approximate idea of the sales occurring.

### What I've done so far:

So far, I've made a table that has the aforementioned columns as well as a DATETIME of when I insert it into my db and then my own string version of the day it was inserted (YYYYMMDD). I made the combo of the Seller, Category, Price, and My YYYYMMDD date my primary key. I contemplated just searching for entries less than 10hrs old prior to insert, but I'm doing this operation on about 50k entries per hour so i'm afraid of that being too much of a load for the system(I don't know however, MySql is not my forte). What I'm currently doing is I've set the rule that I'm ok w/ only allowing the recording of 1 sale per day(this is done by my pk being the combo of the values i mentioned above), but i discovered that a sale made at 10pm will end up w/ a duplicate added the next day at 1am because the value hasn't time out yet and it's considered unique once again because the date has changed.

### What would you do?

I'd love any ideas on how you'd go about achieving something like this. I'm open to all suggestions and I'm ok if the solution results in a seller only having 1 unique sale per day.

Thanks alot folks, I've been staring this problem down for a week now and I feel it's time to get some fresh eyes on it. Any comments are appreciated!

**Update** - While toying around w/ the thought that I basically want to disable entries for a given pseudo pk (seller-category-price) into the database for 10 hrs each time, it occured to me, what if i had a two stage insert process. Any time I got unqiue values I could put them in a stage one table that stores the data plus a time stamp of entry. If a duplicate tries to get inserted, I just ignore it. After 10hrs, I move those values from the stage 1 table to my final values table thus re-allowing entry for a duplicate sale after 10 hours. I think this would even allow multiple sales w/ overlapping time w/ just a bit of a delay. Say sales occured at 1pm and 6pm, the 1pm entry would be in the 1st stage table until 11pm and then once it got moved, the 6pm entry would be recorded, just 5 hours late(unfortunately the value would end up w/ a 5hr off insert date too which could move a sale to the next day, but i'm ok with that). This avoids the big issue i feared of querying the db on every insert for duplicates. The only thing it complicates is live viewing of the data, but i think doing a query from 2 different tables shouldn't be too bad. What do you guys and gals think? See any flaws in this method?

Comment: Do these entries always stick around for the full ten hours, or is there a chance they'll disappear earlier?  If they all survive for about ten hours, you can get a good approximation by querying the site every ten hours and assuming you never get a duplicate.

Comment: I agree with Xavier's idea - here's another suggestion too -- Say for every new record you insert into your table, you take the primary key for it, upload it into a second table along with all the data for the transaction above it?  So in your example, say Mike's Autonumber ID is 50, once he's uploaded put a record in a second table with a FK of 50, and populate it with Joe's data.  Compare to that table before every upload and you decreate the likelihood of dups.  I don't know any JSON but I like the question

Comment: The url returns the last 25 entries for a max time of 10hrs, so on a busy day there is potential for an entry to get removed from the list before its 10 hours have passed. Sadly the data is sorted each time it's returned so I can't infer any sequence data based off it's position in the list. Thanks for these suggestions tho, it's giving me a couple more ideas that I can almost fully think through, but haven't put my finger on yet ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is less about how to store the data than how to recognize which records are distinct in the first place (despite the fact there is no timestamp or transaction ID to distinguish them). If you can distinguish logically distinct records, then you can create a distinct synthetic ID or timestamp, or do whatever you prefer to store the data.

The approach I would recommend is to sample the URL frequently. If you can consistently harvest the data considerably faster than it is updated, you will be able to determine which records have been observed before by noting the sequence of records that precede them.

Assuming the fields in each record have some variability, it would be very improbable for the same sequence of 5 or 10 or 15 records to occur in a 10-hour period. So as long as you sample the data quickly enough to that only a fraction of the 25 records are rolled over each time, your conclusion would be very confident.  This is similar to how DNA is sequenced in a "shotgun" algorithm.

You can determine how frequent the samples need to be by just taking samples and measuring how often you don't see enough prior records -- dial the sample frequency up or down.

Comment: Unfortunately each hour I look at about 3,300 items which can each return 25 sales so at it's max i can hit 80k values to process which I think will cancel out the option of doing quick observations(on avg i see about a 5minute runtime on my script as it's querying 3,300 url's to get the json data). Regarding checking sequences, they sadly return the data sorted by price which negates any fifo/queue ordering that might have inherently provided some tangible sequence info.

Comment: The sorting behavior doesn't help, but you can still use the basic approach of examining epochs of data to determine which records are new vs. old.  You have a touch row to hoe if this is the only API available to you, but it could still work. If the overall run time of the script is an issue, there are lots of ways to deal with that -- parallelize the script with subprocesses, or run multiple instances of the script, many other ways.